# How to optimize/ make this c code even faster?

Tags: c, performance, loops, optimization

I need to optimize this c code in order for it to run as fast as possible. I am quite new to code optimization in general. What should I begin with?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  int n, i, flag;
  int sumOfPrimeNumbers; //sum of prime numbers
    sumOfPrimeNumbers = 0;
    do {
      flag = 0;
      scanf("%d", &n);
      for(i=2;i < n;i++)
      {
        if(n%i==0) {
          flag=1; // flag all non-prime numbers
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag==0) {
        sumOfPrimeNumbers = sumOfPrimeNumbers + n; // sum prime numbers
      }
    } while (n != 0);
printf("%d\n", sumOfPrimeNumbers);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a [prime number sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_primes#Prime_sieves), such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), to find the primes in the wanted range.

Comment: `for (i=2;i < n;i++)` : I think you can stop at `sqrt(n)` or something like that and you don't need to check pair numbers as they are obviously not prime. So just assume 2 is prime, and then check 3, 5, 7, 9 etc, this alone will get you roughly a 100% speed increase

Comment: After you get scanf out of the loop, things are fast enough as long as you are dealing with relatively small numbers.

Comment: Note that you don't need to search up to N-1; up to and including
`ceil(sqrt(N))` is sufficient.
If N is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other
is not smaller than √N).
After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd
numbers.
If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger
primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1.
Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in
the thousands, let alone much bigger.
Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Comment: If the range to be searched is big enough (the maximum value is large
enough), building a Sieve of Eratosthenes (or even more advanced
techniques — such as Sieve of Atkin) for the primes up to the square
root of the maximum and then testing only the 'known to be prime'
possible factors can be beneficial.

Eventually, deterministic evaluation of 'is it a prime' becomes too slow
and you resort to probabilistic prime detection such as the Miller-Rabin
test.

See Wikipedia on [Primality
test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: Another thing if you are working through a range of primes from 2 upward is to build an array of primes found so far, and use *only them* for the divisibility test (up the square root). If you have tested with `3` then there is no need to test with `9`.

Comment: For code optimization try compiler flags ...but no compiler will improve the `O()` of your algorithm: you need to use a different algorithm (and code) for that

Comment: Make or get a table of all primes in your domain and lookup.  Memory isn't a concern right?  :)

Comment: Sieve of Atkin (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) only recently came to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small values of `n` (maybe values less than 66536?) you can use a table of precomputed answers, like "`printf("%d\n", table[n]);`".

For larger values you can split `n` into "zone" and "offset in zone", like "`zone = n / zone_size; offset = n % zone_size;`" and then use "zone" as an index into a precomputed table to determine an initial starting point (and skip a huge amount of work, like "`sumOfPrimeNumbers = zoneStartTable[n / zone_size;`"). The "offset in zone" part can be used with Sieve of Eratosthenes; which means that it's nicer for "zone_size" to be the product of the smallest primes (e.g. maybe like "`zone_size = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17;`") because that makes it a little easier to create a Sieve of Eratosthenes from a non-zero starting point.

For this approach to work you will actually need 2 sieves - one to find primes from 1 to "sqrt(n)" so that you can mark multiples of those primes as "not prime" in the second sieve (which will contain values from "zone * zone_size" to n). This process can be accelerated by recognizing that the sieve for the smallest primes (that you used to determine "zone_size") create a pattern that repeats every "zone_size" numbers, and that pattern can be predetermined and then copied into both of the sieves to initialize the sieves, allowing you to skip marking the smallest primes in both sieves.

Answer (score 1):

Improve the algorithm.  Avoid  [premature optimizations](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

- Rather than test up to `n`, search to the square root of `n`

  ```
    // for(i=2;i < n;i++)
    for (i=2; i <= n/i; i++)
  ```
- [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)
- Form a list of found primes {2,3,5} and only test against those.  As a new prime is found, append it to the list.

Many other optimizations possible.